# Meteor: Change the Iron Router Data Reactive Variable Without Page Reload

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In my meteor app, I am using iron-router's `waitOn` method to subscribe to all relevant documents and the `data` method to return just one document's contents to the template as a reactive variable. (Since these documents are large, I want to load just one at a time as a reactive variable for speed concerns).

```
  //...
  waitOn: function() {
    // subscribe to ohlcOneMin, ohlcThreeMin, etc.
    return Meteor.subscribe(this.params.exchange, this.params.market);
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      ohlc: Widgets_Exchanges_Btcchina.findOne({market: this.params.market, dataType:'ohlcOneMin'})
    };
  },
  //...
```

By default on route load, iron-router will store data from the `ohlcOneMin` document under the `Router.current().data().ohlc` reactive variable. And that works great in my template. Now, imagine I have a button in my template. On click, it would change the iron-router data source to the contents of the `ohlcThreeMin` document... essentially toggling iron-router's `Router.current().data()` reactive variable between different document data which the user is subscribed to, without having to re-load the route or have all the data from all the documents stored in a reactive variable at the same time. How can this be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: You could just have your route's `data` function call a `Session` variable for the `dataType`. Then just have your button change the `Session` value.

Comment: @sbking that sounds like a plausible approach. Are you able to provide some code snippets to help me get started? Thanks!